# Sleep and Wake Arduino according to LDR interrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, sleep

I have to sleep the system in the night and have to wake the system in day time. I am using LDR to get input. LDR input is connected to interrupt pin 0 of Arduino Uno.

Here is my code.

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>
int led =13;
int triggerPin = 2;

void wakeUpNow() 
{

}

void setup()
{
pinMode(triggerPin, INPUT);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
attachInterrupt(0, sleepNow, LOW); 
}

void loop()
{
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);;
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}

void sleepNow() 
{
set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN); 
sleep_enable(); 
attachInterrupt(0,wakeUpNow, RISING); 
sleep_mode(); 
sleep_disable();
detachInterrupt(0); 
}
```

Cannot we attach two function in a interrupt?

**Edited**
The following code works perfectly. I want to replace the conditional check with interrupt.

```
#include <avr/sleep.h>
int led =13;
int wakePin = 2; 

void wakeUpNow() 
{
delay(100);
}

void setup()
{
pinMode(wakePin, INPUT);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
//attachInterrupt(0, sleepNow, LOW); 
}

void loop()
{
digitalWrite(led, HIGH);;
delay(1000);
digitalWrite(led, LOW);

if(digitalRead(wakePin)==LOW)
  sleepNow(); 

}

void sleepNow() 
{
set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN); 
sleep_enable(); 
attachInterrupt(0,wakeUpNow, RISING); function
sleep_mode(); 
sleep_disable(); 
detachInterrupt(0);
}
```

I want to replace `

```
if(digitalRead(wakePin)==LOW)
  sleepNow()
```

with`

```
attachInterrupt(0, sleepNow, LOW);
```

Please let me know how I can do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks to me like you're attaching an interrupt and then immediately detaching it. Could you explain why?

Comment: After attach the interrupt, it goes to sleep. When it wake up from sleep, it detach from the interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to replace the conditional check with interrupt.

Why? If it is awake it might just as well be testing the pin as doing anything else.

If you make it an interrupt, in the ISR interrupts will be off. Then if you go to sleep it will never wake.

So, your current design is the correct one, except:

```
attachInterrupt(0,wakeUpNow, RISING); function
```

What is `function` doing there?

Comment: The function is not necessary. The normal interrupt automatically wakes up the system.  Is that so?

Comment: But we have to add the interrupt to wake up the system when LDR gives output high. Isn't it? Otherwise how will the system wake up?

Comment: Yes, you wake when the LDR goes high. But why do you want to have an interrupt when it goes LOW? It is already awake.